# Horizontal align overbrace

Tags: horizontal-alignment, overbrace

In my attempt to horizontal align two overbraces, the original equations gets skewed.  Can you help me to correctly align the equation and overbraces?

[image]

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
AF_{\substack{m=1/3\\n=1.9-2}}=\overbrace{\left(\dfrac{\Delta T_{new}}{\Delta T_{eALT}}\right)^{-n\vphantom{\dfrac{1}{T_{\substack{eALT\\max}}}}}}^{\Delta T}
\times
\overbrace{e^{\left(\left(\dfrac{E_{a}}{k}\right)\times \left(\dfrac{1}{T_{new}}-\dfrac{1}{T_{\substack{eALT\\max}}}\right)\right)}}^{Arrhenius}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would use exp for that.

Comment: unrelated but use `\mathrm{max}` , `\mathrm{new}` etc, the default math italic is designed with wide sidebearings so adjacent letters do not look like a word but like a product of variables.

Comment: @JouleV...can you extrapolate on your suggestion?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would rearrange the equation as follows:

[image]

If you look closely at the code, you'll notice the `^{\vphantom{t}}` particle -- it's a (typographic) strut which raises the second overbrace by a small amount, so that it's aligned horizontally with the first overbrace.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \substack macro
\newcommand{\vn}[1]{\mathrm{#1}} % to typeset variable names
\begin{document}

\[
\vn{AF}_{\!\!\substack{m=1/3\\n=1.9-2}}
={\overbrace{\biggl(
  \frac{\Delta T_{\vn{new}}}{\Delta T_{\vn{eALT}}}\biggr)^{\!-n}}^{\Delta T}}
\times
\overbrace{\exp \biggl[ \frac{E_{a}}{k} \biggl( \frac{1}{T_{\vn{new}}}
 -\frac{1}{T_{\substack{\vn{eALT}\\\max}}} \biggr)^{\vphantom{t}} 
 \biggr]}^{\vn{Arrhenius}}
\]

\end{document}
```